Homomorphisms between $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ and $\mathbb C$? and solvabity of an equation
I am required to find the field homomorphisms between $K = \mathbb Q[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ and $\mathbb C$ and to show that for any $n \geq 1$ the equation
$$x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = -1 \qquad x_i \in K $$
has no solution.
For the first problem, my idea is this.First notice that $K = \{r_0 + r_1x +r_2 x^2: r_i \in \mathbb Q: x^3 -2=0 \}$  Let $f: K \to \mathbb C$ be a field homomorphism, suppose that $f(x) = z$ then $f(x^3 - 2) = 0$ and consequently
$z^3 = 2$ and this equation has three solutions, which are $z_1 = \sqrt[3]{2},z_2 = 2^{-2/3}(1+\sqrt{3}i), z_3 = 2^{-2/3}(1-\sqrt{3}i)$ and hence there are three homomorphism and they are $f_i(r_0 + r_1x + r_2 x^2) = r_0  +r_2 z_i +r_3 z_i^2$.
Is this correct?
For the second problem, I first thought of taking one of the homomorphism and trying to derive a contradiction but I couldn't find any contradiction. So I followed a direct approach and computer $x_i^2$ and found a system of equations, I managed to find a contradiction for the case $n=1$ but I can't find it for general $n$. So basically I did this. If
$$ x_i = r_0^i + r_1^i x + r_2^i x^2 $$
then $$(x_i)^2 = (r_0^i)^2 + (r_1^i)^2 x^2 + 2(r_2^i)^2x 
         + 2r_0^ir_1^ix + 4r_1^ir_2^i + 2r_0^ir_2^i x^2 $$
so that we obtain the equations
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (r_0^i)^2 + 4r_1^ir_2^i = -1$$
$$  \sum_{i=1}^n  2(r_2^i)^2+2r_0^ir_1^i = 0$$
$$  \sum_{i=1}^n  (r_1^i)^2 +  2r_0^ir_2^i  = 0$$
So in the case $n = 1$ I can find a contradiction by considering the values of the coefficients with cases but I couldnt find a contradiction for the general case. So any help is appreciated

For the first part, your answer is correct.
For the second part, if there was a solution, then there will be a solution in the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, corresponding to an embedding $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. In particular you can use the embedding given by $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{2}$. The subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ we obatin this way is a real subfield, i.e it is inside $\mathbb{R}$, where clearly the equation $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = -1$ has no solutions. Thus we are done !.

thank you, I don't know why I didn't notice that and instead I was trying to do computations ahah

You are welcome.
